# Relative block div taller than content - unexplained white space

Tags: html, css

I am working on a simple form with pure css help boxes that appear when the user hovers over the row that the help box is in.

I did not open my project for a few days, and when I opened it this morning there were a few bugs, which have mostly been fixed. (excessive page width for no reason, fixed by adding 'overflow-x: hidden' to body, etc) But the current problem is that there is added white space above the p element inside '.help-box'.

I'm not sure what is causing it, if you have time please have a look at this JSFiddle that I have created:
https://jsfiddle.net/alecbach/7j6b6xn2/5/

Here is the CSS for the .help-box:

```
.help-cont{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 10px;
    height: 0px;
    width: calc(100% - 8px);
    top: -56px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, margin-top 0.3s ease-in-out;
    .help-box{
        position: relative;
        top: 12px;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: white
    }
}
```

(ignore the script errors, it's just the script loading before google maps and jquery have. they do not effect the state of the site)

Edit: Here's a gif showing the white space:
https://gyazo.com/96410bb189104af914fd921c1d12fa56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: absolute;` to `.help-cont` ***instead of*** *relative*. By using relative it's taking the flow of other elements into account and pushing down the text.

Try that and it works. It then just has the margin bottom of the `p` element which is easy enough to sort out to make it even around all edges.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the explanation.